# Modelling multiple days of the week

Tags: java, date, dayofweek

This is the second time i've come accross a one-many relationship between object and weekday and I'm not sure if i'm modelling it in the best way:

```
@Entity
MyObject {
    private int id;
    private String foo;
    private boolean monday;
    private boolean tuesday;
    private boolean wednesday;
    private boolean thursday;
    private boolean friday;
    private boolean saturday;
    private boolean sunday;
}
```

Has anyone come across a better way of doing this?

My requirement is to retrieve all instances of `MyObject` from the db that match the current day of the week, i.e. no need to check multiple days for example mon=1 && tues=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When modeling a finite number of items in a set, it is usually best to use an [`enum`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).

```
public enum DayOfWeek {
    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
}
```

You might use this in your class like so:

```
class YourClass {
    private Set<DayOfWeek> activeDays;

    public void addActiveDay(DayOfWeek day){
        activeDays.add(day);
    }
}
...

yourclass.addActiveDay(DayOfWeek.Friday);
```

Comment: As in:

`MyObject { Set<DayOfWeek> activeWeekdays }` ?

Comment: It seems like a far greater overhead on the database? An extra table to join on, potentially 7 varchar(9).

Comment: @James, you are probably correct.  This would not perform better than representing the days at integers.  However, it is usually best practice to design good code first, and then worry about optimization. You can't be sure that using enums will be too slow.

Answer (score 0):

How about create an enum of days of the week, and then have a private array that stores the days that are applicable? If you want to get fancy, you could have some structure (such as a `Set`, which I think does not allow duplicates) other than an array that prevents duplicates.

If you're also using this with a database, what kind of query are you running to get data, and what kind of table structure are you using (enum solutions may not work with all databases)?

Comment: I would use Mysql/InnoDb with a table `MyObjects(ID:int, FOO: varchar, MONDAY: bit, TUESDAY: bit ... SUNDAY: bit)` and then query for example `where MONDAY=1`

Comment: @James: MySQL has Enums and they do seem compatible with Java (though I haven't tried it myself): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html  ...Though this would require modifying your existing tables and queries.